# Methods allowed by RPCs providers for contracts Solidity Event listeners at etherjs

Tags: solidity, events, polygon, rpc, zksync

GM everyone.

I'll appreciate any help to know how is the correct form of consume events in a backend listener of EVM solidity contracts, and if can share your favorite Rpcs Providers like infura,quicknode etc, to help listen events on a contract. I have been used this structure on Polygon Mainnet:
(Tried with Etherjs 6.11.0 and 6.9.2)

Solidity code snippet:

```
function evemitest(uint8 typex, string memory msgx ,string memory token) onlyOwner public{
    emit eventx(msg.sender, typex , msgx, token);
}
```

TS backend code snippet:

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
const rpcPolygon = "https://polygon-mainnet.infura.io/v3/..."
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(rpcPolygon);
const contract = new ethers.Contract("0x...", ABIv9, provider)

contract.on('eventx', async (who:any,typeEvent:any,msgx:any,token:any) => {
    console.log(`[eventx] From: ${who}, typeEv: ${typeEvent}, msgx: ${msgx}`)
};
```

Obtaining the next error:

```
@TODO Error: could not coalesce error (
error={ "code": -32004, "message": "method not supported eth_newFilter" }, 
payload={ "id": 2, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_newFilter", 
"params": [ { "address": [ "0xf008261fe6ca854d23c026bf8a5d884230c1d5b9" ], 
"topics": [ "0xe8b1b44e54ce7decd5e9c156eeef682592ecc18c8f83bfd2fc384e2a9d57e06e" ] } ] }, 
code=UNKNOWN_ERROR, version=6.9.2)
at makeError (C:.\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\utils\errors.js:129:21)
at JsonRpcProvider.getRpcError (C:.\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\provider-jsonrpc.js:722:41)
at C:.\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\provider-jsonrpc.js:302:45
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
code: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR',
error: { code: -32004, message: 'method not supported eth_newFilter' },
payload: {
  method: 'eth_newFilter',
  params: [ [Object] ],
  id: 2,
  jsonrpc: '2.0'
},
shortMessage: 'could not coalesce error'
```

with this behavior at InfuraRPC in Polygon Mainnet  :

```
{ code: -32004, message: 'method not supported eth_newFilter' }
method: 'eth_newFilter'
```

I also check the RPC methods allowed at infura...
notice that it does not exist at: https://docs.infura.io/api/networks/polygon-pos/json-rpc-methods

I also tryed the same contract at zksync Sepolia Testnet (my main project*) through quicknode RPC endpoint, and taking other missing method:

```
@TODO Error: could not coalesce error (error={ "code": -32602, "message": "Filter not found" }, 
payload={ "id": 16, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_getFilterChanges", 
"params": [ "0x85d195d66364506624fc7da62bec83cc937c092dc6c2265fdc54ee370a9a4e09" ] },
code=UNKNOWN_ERROR, version=6.11.1)
at makeError (C:...\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\utils\errors.js:129:21)
at C:\...\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\provider-jsonrpc.js:302:45
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
code: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR',
error: { code: -32602, message: 'Filter not found' },
payload: {
method: 'eth_getFilterChanges',
params: [
  '0x85d195d66364506624fc7da62bec83cc937c092dc6c2265fdc54ee370a9a4e09'
],
id: 16,
jsonrpc: '2.0'
},
shortMessage: 'could not coalesce error'}
```

Notice this relevant stuff on this RPC behavior at zksync sepolia testnet QuicknodeRPC:

```
error: { code: -32602, message: 'Filter not found' }
"method": "eth_getFilterChanges"
```

Some interesting think is that sometimes my code at zksync works and listen the events well, until the error JUMPS, and i dont know why.

I know that the public RPCs dont support all methods.

I'll appreciate all help to know:

- if this is the correct way to listening events?
- whats your favorite RPCprovider to consume for listen events
- How i can know every method that is used for the contract.on( ) ...

Thank you very much!!!